# What is the meaning of delegate{ }

Tags: c#, delegates

Can someone  please explain the meaning of `delegate{ }` below

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };
```

Also why does it eliminate the need for a null reference check on CanExecuteChanged, and what (if any) are the potential performance hits for using it.

Comment: Put simply, it's an empty method (so now `CanExecuteChanged` is bound to a ["NOOP"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP))

Answer (score 8):

This is a [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) value for parameterless delegate. It represents an anonymous method that does nothing.

It eliminates the need for `null`-checking because you can call such delegate without triggering a null reference exception.

**Note:** This trick becomes less relevant in C# 6.0, because the language provides an alternative syntax to calling delegates that may be `null`:

```
delegateThatCouldBeNull?.Invoke(this, value);
```

Above, null conditional operator `?.` combines null checking with a conditional invocation.

Answer (score 3):

Here `delegate { }` is an `Anonymous method block` which will act as an event handler for the hooked up event. You can write necessary event processing logic here. Example below:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate {
Console.WriteLine("CanExecuteChanged Event has been fired"); };
```

Answer (score 3):

`delegate {}` is an [anonymous method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) with an empty body.  It's a method that does nothing.  The `CanExecuteChanged` event will always have a delegate assigned to it so it will never be null.

The only down side is that you've created a new delegate instance that will live in memory.